# Why this code gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')" error?

Tags: javascript

In this code I am getting error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')

```
console.log("HI");
let addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");
addbtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let addtxt = document.getElementById("addtxt");
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }

  notesObj.push(addtxt.value);
  //getting error at this point. Don't know why
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addtxt = "";
  console.log(notesObj);
});
```

Comment: Just declare the notesObj (  local or global before using ) as an array variable ! It will solve the issue

Comment: notesObj is null maybe ?

Comment: @Sanmeet I have declared notesObj=[ ]; after if(notes==null)

Comment: The error is not reproducible. Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre]. Is Local Storage enabled?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this I hope it will fix your problem

```
let addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");
console.log('addbtn ', addbtn);

addbtn?.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let addtxt = document.getElementById("addtxt");
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");

  notesObj = JSON.parse(notes ?? '[]');

  console.log('addtxt.value ', addtxt?.value);

  notesObj.push(addtxt.value);
  //getting error at this point. Don't know why
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addtxt = "";
  console.log(notesObj);
});
```

Comment: Still same error @md. motailab

Comment: It should be || instead of ??, not?

Comment: `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: @DEBANJANBHATTACHARJEE please check the updated code I think now you will be able to identify your problem I added some consoles.log it will be helpful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the string `'null'` in your local storage.

Yes you compare with `null`, but `notes` is still JSON at this point, and apparently it can be `null` encoded as JSON. So you'd also need to check for `'null'` as string.

Or, easier: Replace the whole `if` with something like this:

```js
const notesObj = (notes && JSON.parse(notes)) ?? []
```

If you want to be also resilient against invalid JSON in local storage, you can use this:

```js
let notesObj
try {
  notesObj = JSON.stringify(notes) ?? []
} catch(e) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

to fix this issue use localstorage.clear() in the console. that's it.

Comment: This may clear the immediate problem but won't make the code robust against having `'null'` in local storage like you had it before.