# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'onclick')

Tags: javascript, electron

I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'onclick')` on following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yqDxhR2XxE&t=4s

Here is the `main.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Electron recorder</h1>
    <video></video>

    <button id="startBtn" class="button is-primary"></button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="button is-warning"></button>

    <hr />
    <button id="videoSelectionBtn" class="button is-text"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in `render.js`, following lines seems buggy:

```
console.log(videoSelectionBtn)          // prints NULL 
videoSelectionBtn.onclick() = getVideoResources;
```

whole file

```
// Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.querySelector('stopBtn');
const videoSelectionBtn = document.querySelector('videoSelectionBtn');

console.log(videoSelectionBtn)          // prints NULL 
videoSelectionBtn.onclick() = getVideoResources;


const { desktopCapturer, remote } = require('electron')
const { Menu } = remote;

async function getVideoResources() {
    const inputSource = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
        types: ['window', 'screen']
    })

    const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
        inputSource.map(source => {
            return {
                label: source.name,
                click: () => selectSource(source) 
            };
        })
    );

    videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

async function selectSource(source) {
    videoSelectionBtn.innerText = source.name;
    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'dekstop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
            }
        }
    };

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

    videoElement.srcObject = stream;
    videoElement.play();
}
```

Can someone please help explain -

1. How to go about debugging such instances. Different things I could have checked before posting it here
2. What is the actual root cause

PS: The error seems generic and I have gone through the posts (without much help):

- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push') at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:15:23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291219/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-push-at-htmlbutto)
- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920854/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-user)
- [Why this code gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549589/why-this-code-gives-me-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-read)

Comment: because you are looking for `<videoSelectionBtn>` not an id. Your selector is an element selector, not an id selector. `document.querySelector('#videoSelectionBtn')`

Comment: Newbie doubt - but isn't `videoSelectionBtn` an id?

Comment: Yes `id="videoSelectionBtn"` but basic CSS selectors use a `#` for id. When there is no `#` it is a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must query an element's id with **# symbol** or try `document.getElementById('element-id')`, following snippet should do the work, uncomment the import statement of course!

```js
// Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('#video');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.querySelector('#stopBtn');
const videoSelectionBtn = document.querySelector('#videoSelectionBtn');

console.log(videoSelectionBtn)          // prints NULL 
videoSelectionBtn.onclick = getVideoResources;


// const { desktopCapturer, remote } = require('electron')
// const { Menu } = remote;

async function getVideoResources() {
    const inputSource = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
        types: ['window', 'screen']
    })

    const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
        inputSource.map(source => {
            return {
                label: source.name,
                click: () => selectSource(source) 
            };
        })
    );

    videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

async function selectSource(source) {
    videoSelectionBtn.innerText = source.name;
    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'dekstop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
            }
        }
    };

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

    videoElement.srcObject = stream;
    videoElement.play();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Electron recorder</h1>
    <video></video>

    <button id="startBtn" class="button is-primary"></button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="button is-warning"></button>

    <hr />
    <button id="videoSelectionBtn" class="button is-text"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```